# creating array through class object

Tags: php

I want to create a multidimensional array through class object. Don't know the syntax. Kindly guide me regarding that.

```
class gridcell {
    var $place;
    var $latitude;

    $spatial=array();
    $temporal=array();
    $taxi=array();


    $raiwind = new gridell();
    $raiwind->place("raiwind");
    $raiwind->latitude("31.4279");
```

Now I wanted to put the following array in the `$raiwind->$spatial`
What would be its synatx. Different objects have different elements in `$spatial` array.

```
spatial(
    array(
        array(
            'lda',
            '31.4104',
            3
        ),
        array(
            'ali',
            '31.3998',
            3
        ),
        array(
            'multan',
            '31.4675',
            10
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: $raiwind->spatial = array(...);

Answer (score 1):

Simple as this:

```
$raiwind->spatial[] = array(
  array('lda','31.4104',3),
  array('ali','31.3998',3),
  array('multan','31.4675',10)
);
```